# No tag library could be found with this URI -AjaxAnywhere when deployed on weblogic 11g

Tags: java, ajax, jsp-tags, weblogic11g, tld

When I deploy the sample ajaxanywhere application on weblogic 8.x it works great. When I deploy it to weblogic 11g I get the error below

```
disp2.jsp:2:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib prefix="aa" uri="http://ajaxanywhere.sourceforge.net/" %>
^----^
```

The sample app can be downloaded from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxanywhere/files/AjaxAnywhere%20Demo%20WAR/1.2/ (i used 1.2 but 1.2-rc3 has the same issue).

I have tried ...

1. extracting the TLDs from the jar file and putting them under web-inf and referencing them from web.xml
2. adding jstl1.0.6 to the lib directory and putting "prefer web classes" in weblogic.xml.

Still have the same issue. I am willing rebuild ajaxanywhere from source if I can determine what is wrong. I am leaning towards some sort of JSTL library incompatibility.\

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oracle support found that if the trailing slash was removed from the URI it worked. so instead of

```
URI=http://ajaxanywhere.sourceforge.net/
```

the URI should be

```
URI=http://ajaxanywhere.sourceforge.net
```